# efficient way to change BGR to grayscale image and then use LUT

Tags: c++, opencv

I have got a BGR image and I am trying to map a lookup table based on its intensity. It works and I do it the following way:

```
cv::cvtColor(original_frame, gray_frame, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cv::cvtColor(gray_frame, gray_frame3,cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
LUT(gray_frame3, mylut, pcolor_frame);
```

This seems very inefficient to me. At first I change the original BGR to a single-channel grayscale which I then expand into 3 channels to use with LUT.

Can I somehow improve speed by

- directly converting the original image into a 3-channel grayscale image or
- by using a single-channel grayscale image to map to the look-up table?

Comment: I don't know enough CV API from head, but the second option sounds like what I would design if I would write everything from scratch, there's no point to have 3 same grayscale values as part of key, or LUT or anything (except if that's the only way how the CV API can be bend to achieve what you need). From my limited experience with openCV the API is usually flexible and sane enough. BTW from your question it is not clear how you intend to use your new LUT, maybe that would also give some idea how to proceed further. "As is, simply remove it at all, as it doesn't get used." - sort of joke ;)

Comment: Most efficient way is loop by yourself.

Comment: @Silencer that's an interesting statement, I wonder how much overhead the cvtColor function does actually add than doing it yourself.

Comment: @GPPK  At least in C++, the time and memory costing of the special ops can be measured by your self if you really want to measure. Simple analysis, use two cvtColor, you must create two Mat, that cost time. And do more loop, at least twice than by your self. `LUT` is fast because the OpenCV is multi-thread enabled via Intel Threaded Building Blocks.  Loop by yourself, only need one Mat construction. Then enable MT via TBB(first you should know how), avoid unnecessary op, It must be faster.

Comment: @GPPK  Accurate time costing report needs experiment. The poster just said `This seems very inefficient to me.`  Also without accurate time cost report.

Comment: O sure, I'd be interested to see the results but I can't be bothered to do it myself. More of an interested party!

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input! It seems there is no out-of-the-box way to do this. Writing my own function would provide me with the possibility to do an in-place conversion for the original color image straight to the pseudocolor result by calculating the intensity for each pixel and writing back the results of the pseudocolor lookup. However I usually try to not do these things as I assume others have optimized and debugged the existing methods.